# logrotate frequency - when and from when

Tags: linux, centos, logging, syslog, logrotate

if have lograte in my daily cron

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate  -- assume cron.daily is run at 1.05am daily
```

and if my logrotate config has a

```
weekly
```

settings

Does it means that my logrotate will run daily, but the logs will only be rotated weekly ?
and 
weekly since when/what time ? *-- (since the logfile creation time or since the last time logrotate runs ?)*

Answer (score 2):

> Does it means that my logrotate will run daily, but the logs will only be rotated weekly ?

Yes.

> weekly since when/what time ?

[Documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)

> **weekly**
>   Log files are rotated if the current weekday is less than the weekday of the last rotation or if more than a week has passed since the last rotation. This is normally the same as rotating logs on the first day of the week, but it works better if logrotate is not run every night.

Comment: @lain thanks, I read the same part of documentation. So the weekly is counted since the last rotation done -> if this is the 1st time that the logrotate is run , then can I say that nothing will be rotated until 7 days later ?

Comment: are you still there ?